# select angularjs variable using function parameter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've some function like this:

```
$scope.activeimageset = function(id){}
```

Now, I pass some parameter as ID to mentioned function, and I want to select some variable using gathered parameter, something like this:

```
$scope.activeimageset = function(id){$scope.img{{id}}.src1 = $scope.img{{id}}.src2;}
```

That's mean I want to select some object using parameter passed to my function and then I set one of the attributes of that object to another attribute. How can I do that? I know my code is wrong and doesn't work, but I want to know how can I make it work?

Comment: What is the error? Is `id` undefined in the function body?

Comment: do not use parenthesis `{{}}` inside your ngController, please provide some more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite your function like this:

```
$scope.activeimageset = function(id){
  $scope['img' + id].src1 = $scope['img' + id].src2;
};
```

In JS you can use two ways to obtain properties values, they are [**Dot Notation** and **Square Bracket Notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

[Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/2dawdvh0/) the very basic example of using these ways:

```
var obj = {
 prop1: 'prop1 value',
 prop2: [1,2,3]
}

var propName = 'prop2';

console.log(obj.prop1); // 'prop1 value'
console.log(obj[propName]); '[1, 2, 3]'
```

In summary:

- Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.
- Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing
  special characters and selection of properties using variables (just like in your case).

Comment: Thank you so much for your code, It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Here assuming that you have list of images as array

You have to find out the object from images array based on passed parameter i.e. *id*.

In your controller

```
$scope.imgs = [{
    id: 1,
    src1: 'red.jpg',
    src2: 'green.jpg'
}, {
    id: 2,
    src1: 'black.jpg'.
    src2: 'yellow.jpg'
}]

$scope.activeimageset = function(id){
   $scope.img = $scope.imgs.filter(function(img) {
       return img.id === id;
   });
   $scope.img.src1 = $scope.img.src2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.activeimageset = function(id) {
   $scope.listOfObjs; //it is array where all objects are stored
   $scope.dummyAttr; //attr you want to change from object you will get from param
   var requiredObj = ($scope.listOfObjs).filter(function( obj ) {
      return obj.id === id; //returns object with passed id
   });
   $scope.dummyAttr = requiredObj.attr;
}
```

Hope thats what you were looking for